# How to know field type in a class

Tags: dart

Suppose I have a class like this :

```
class SomeClass {
  String name;
  int age;
}
```

How can we know `name`'s or `age`'s type without assigning its value e.g. by its declaration ?

**Edit:**

There's `type` getter on `VariableMirror`, don't know how I miss that.

Comment: Have you considered `.runtimeType` or `dart:mirrors`?

Comment: I did, but since `.runtimeType` evaluate by its current value, it is always null. What I want is something like `.returnType` on `MethodMirror`.